# GCM Push Notification registration call returns ok but device is not registered

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Using Phonegap Build to use a push notifications requests for Android devices, when doing registration the request and see what's happened!

```
    var pushNotification=window.plugins.pushNotification;

    var return = pushNotification.register(successHandler , errorHandler,{"senderID":GCMProject,"ecb":"onNotification"});


function successHandler (result) {
    alert('result = ' + result); // returned 'result = ok' //
}

function errorHandler (error) {
    alert('error = ' + error);
}


function onNotification(e) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

    switch( e.event )
    {
    case 'registered':
        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
            // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
            console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
        }
    break;

    case 'message':
        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
        if ( e.foreground )
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

            // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
            // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
            var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
            // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
            var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);
            my_media.play();
        }
        else
        {  // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
            if ( e.coldstart )
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            }
            else
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            }
        }

       $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
           //Only works for GCM
       $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');

    break;

    case 'error':
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
    break;

    default:
        alert('EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is');
    break;
  }
}
```

The `successHandler()` is fired with ('ok') message result!

Why  `the onNotification()` method is not fired any time???

The application is not deployed on Play Store yet. It is used locally but connected to the internet.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: This code only registers. Who is sending you the notification? Take into account that this being has to communicate to Google servers the message and the registrationId...

Comment: Using Puship.com, we have used the phonegap build api from the link below: http://www.puship.com/documentations/platform-setup/ Phonegap online build, but why the response not returned the registration id instread of 'ok' message!

Comment: Before sending or receiving Push Notification , we want to assure that the registration of the devices is correct and done via GCM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the JS Library, when we put the code directly into index.js, it works properly. So the problem wa included into the object define in the PushNotification.js script.